# limiting jquery action to specific elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a slider with multiple elements. Each element has the same structure.

Every element has 3 divs. In the left and right div there is an image, and in the middle div, there is the "open" link". If you click on this link, the left and right div slides away, and the user can see what's behind.

This is working fine so far. But I have a problem if the slider has more elements.

If I'm on the first slide and click on "open" and then slide to the next slide. The left and right div's are already moved ("open"). I would like to have an "per slide" opening, without adding additional classes.

Is it possible to change my jquery code so that if you click the changes are only effecting the elements in the current slider item?

I have the following structure for an item of a slider:

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="content">
        <!-- image -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div clasS="middle">
      <div class="content">
          <!-- content -->
          <a href="#" class="open"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="content ">
        <!-- iamge-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is my jquery Code:

```
$( "a.open" ).click(function() {

  $('.left, .right').toggleClass( "open" );

});
```

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to traverse up the DOM to find your nearest `.item`:

```
// .on() has replaced .click()
$('a.open').on('click', function() {

    $(this).closest('div.item').find('div.left, div.right').toggleClass('open');

});
```

I've also tidied the code up a little bit:

- [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) has replaced `.click()`
- Sizzle (jQuery's CSS engine) will perform better if your right-most argument in each selector contains the tag as well as its class (`div.item` is better than `.item`)

You can also improve your initial `a.open` binding if you instead bind it to the slider element. This way, it'll bind the event once to the parent and listen for clicks inside it, instead of binding once per child (which, if you add new slides programmatically later, would fail on the new slides):

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="mySlider">

// jQuery
$('#mySlider').on('click', 'a.open', function() {
```

Comment: I've just read about .parent() while I've tried your solution. Do you think .parent() is faster than .closest()? With parent I would have to add the class .open to the .container or .item! BTW: Your solution is working well. :)

Comment: `.parent()` is faster, but it only goes up one level. When you're multiple levels down, or your HTML may change, `.closest()` is more flexible, and it's that much slower. If `.closest()` ends up only going up one level (the same distance as `.parent()` then it'll stop there and only be a shade slower anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `this` selector?